# Binding the Key Property of a Keybinding

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023960/keybinding-a-relaycommand) gives a clean method for binding a key at the window level to a ViewModel command in XAML. This is pretty fantastic, but it doesn't allow for customization of the key being used. Is it possible to bind the "key" value to the viewmodel, and if so, what type of value is a "key" in csharp?

```
<Window.InputBindings>
<KeyBinding Key="{Binding RefreshKey}"
            Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
```

Or is it possible to add window-level keybindings in the code? The same question has a solution for putting it in the code-behind, but I would prefer to keep the code in the ViewModel if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keygesture.aspx

> For KeyGesture XAML usages, the property that is generally set in XAML
>   is Gesture, in cases where the gesture represents both a standard key
>   and a modifier key
>
> ...
>   Note that the XAML usage does not directly declare a 
>   element. That object element usage is not possible because KeyGesture
>   does not expose a public default constructor. Instead, the XAML usage
>   uses the typeconverter behavior to declare an entire KeyGesture inline
>   as the Gesture attribute value.

I think you can return a KeyGesture object to bind a Key property or you can always return a composed string and it will be automatically converted

Comment: KeyGesture, perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The property type is the enumeration [Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key.aspx), so it should be simple enough to expose this from your view model and bind to it. However, as noted in the question you linked to, support for bindings in `KeyBinding` were not added until WPF 4.

EDIT: didn't realize you were asking for a way to invoke a command as a result of multiple key strokes. Please see my blog post [here](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/03/multikeygesture.html) discussing how I solved this. You may need to adapt it for WPF 4.

Comment: I don't see how you would return more than one Key using that type. Something like CTRL+R wouldn't be possible in a single value.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. Edited my post.

Comment: I think you still misunderstand. I am not asking for multiple keystrokes, but modified keys. Ctrl+R is one key, as far as windows is concerned.