# WPF Attach a command to a textbox on return key in NET 3.5

Tags: wpf, textbox, .net-3.5, key-bindings, inputbinding

I am trying to attach a command and a commandparameter to a textbox on return key but without success. The parameter is the current text in the same textbox.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSearch">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding  Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" 
                      CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=txtSearch}" Key="Return" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Basically I want to execute the command when user clicks on return/enter key and pass as a parameter the current text in the textbox.

I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023960/keybinding-a-relaycommand) where it is said that in .NET 3.5 command parameter for keybinding is not accepting bindings. So a solution is proposed by code in code-behind but how can I pass a parameter to the command from the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to add the KeyBinding to your TextBox and set its Command on code-behind. Just add this in the constructor of your View:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MyViewModel();

    KeyBinding kb = new KeyBinding();
    kb.Command = (DataContext as MyViewModel).SearchCommand;                        
    kb.Key = Key.Enter;
    txtSearch.InputBindings.Add(kb);
}
```

Then, you can bind the `Text` property of the TextBox named `txtSearch` to a property of your ViewModel. This way you don't need to pass a parameter as you can use the value of that property in your ViewModel inside the code that executes your Command.

Your ViewModel should look like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private string _txtSearch;
    public string TxtSearch
    {
        get { return _txtSearch; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _txtSearch)
            {
                _txtSearch = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TxtSearch");
            }
        }
    }

    private ICommand _searchCommand;
    public ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_searchCommand == null)
            {
                _searchCommand = new RelayCommand(p => canSearch(), p => search());
            }
            return _searchCommand;
        }
    }
    private bool canSearch()
    {
        //implement canExecute logic.
    }
    private void search()
    {
        string text = TxtSearch; //here you'll have the string that represents the text of the TextBox txtSearch
        //DoSomething
    }
}
```

If you have access to C# 6 (Visual Studio 2015 and later versions), you can alter the call to the OnPropertyChanged to: `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TxtSearch));`. This way you get rid of the "magic string" and eventual renaming of the property won't cause any problem for you.

And then your XAML should look like this: (Notice that you need to specify that te UpdateSourceTrigger must be PropertyChanged, so that your `TxtSearch` property of your ViewModel stays up to date when you hit the `Enter` key on your TextBox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TxtSearch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="txtSearch"/>
```

Your ViewModel needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you need a proper ICommand implementation. Here I'll use the RelayCommand.

Those implementations are shown below.

Since your framework is .NET 3.5, implement it like this:

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This is a implementation of the RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler shows below error: a 'binding' cannot be set on the 'command' property of type 'keybinding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject Remember I am using .NET 3.5.

Comment: Well, you'll have to create the Command binding from code-behind then. I'll edit my answer shortly.